# How can I round a value in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

How can I round a value in SQL, used round function .actual result is 555.81 getting 555 script is `round(expression,0)`

this is the result which I used `round(expression,2)` when I use `round(expression,0)` getting 555 as answer

[image: Question image]

Comment: Please add some context to your question. Which should include your desired input output and your actual input and output. Then people over here can help you. [Please Refer How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Have you tried `ROUND( expression )`?

Comment: To improve the quality of your Question, please refer to what research you have performed, and show what attempts you have made (with the full text of any error messages).  Please show all information as text in the question rather than as a link - this is more convenient for the reader.  Also, links can break.

Comment: Use text when you can, not images. Like here. Also please read and act on [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the suggetions.my sql query is very large and the expression too.next time i will give nice explanation

Answer (score 1):

[`ROUND` documentation on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql)

```
select
  [raw]       = 555.81, 
  [rounded]   = round(555.81, 0),
  [truncated] = round(555.81, 0, 1)
```

Result:

```
|    raw | rounded | truncated |
|--------|---------|-----------|
| 555.81 |     556 |       555 |
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/5290

Comment: Actually my expression in query is very large and i used that value in round function but i didnt get output,when i try like this i got correct result.in my expression there is lot of conditions

Comment: While your answer is good, it can be better if you included the relevan quots from MSDN documentation in it. Links can go stale and future readers might not be able to get the MSDN page you've linked to using the link you posted.

Comment: @ZoharPeled that's not type of answer I really care about - that's basically a comment I cannot fit into comment length & format. Feel free to edit my answer if you like

Comment: If you wouldn't bother to do it I wouldn't also.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is rounding down.
    round(expression+0.5,0)
Should work but I have not tested it.